# svg animation - icon not scale center point of icon

Tags: svg, animatetransform

This is the code of my svg, and i am making the animation like heartbeat my icon. but it's not scale center when i give from 1 to 0.
This is the code:

```
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="91.5" y1="104.1582" x2="129.623" y2="104.1582">
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#F99F1C" />
        <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#EB6524" />
    </linearGradient>

    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M115.125,95.979c0,1.116-0.904,2.021-2.021,2.021l0,0c-1.116,0-2.021-0.905-2.021-2.021v-8.834
c0-1.116,0.905-2.021,2.021-2.021l0,0c1.116,0,2.021,0.905,2.021,2.021V95.979z M106.906,116.353c0.789-0.789,0.789-2.068,0-2.857
l0,0c-0.789-0.789-2.068-0.79-2.857,0l-6.247,6.246c-0.79,0.789-0.789,2.068,0,2.857l0,0c0.79,0.79,2.068,0.79,2.857,0
L106.906,116.353z M93.521,105.337c-1.115,0-2.021,0.904-2.021,2.021l0,0c0,1.116,0.905,2.021,2.021,2.021h8.834
c1.116,0,2.021-0.905,2.021-2.021l0,0c0-1.116-0.904-2.021-2.021-2.021H93.521z M100.66,91.51c-0.789-0.789-2.068-0.789-2.857,0l0,0
c-0.789,0.79-0.789,2.069,0,2.858l6.247,6.247c0.789,0.789,2.068,0.789,2.857,0l0,0c0.79-0.789,0.789-2.068,0-2.857L100.66,91.51z
 M129.031,94.368c0.789-0.789,0.789-2.068,0-2.857l0,0c-0.789-0.79-2.068-0.789-2.857,0l-6.246,6.246
c-0.789,0.789-0.789,2.068,0,2.857l0,0c0.789,0.79,2.068,0.789,2.857,0L129.031,94.368z" >
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" id="click1"
        type="scale"
        additive="sum"
        from="1 1"
        to="0 0"
        dur="2s"
        begin="0"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
</path>
```

and this is codepen link:
[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/scalescript/pen/YJZvQq)

let you know, i have more designs in svg path so i just put this one because of i got problem in this icon only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG Scale Animation from Center Point instead of Upper-Left Corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260184/svg-scale-animation-from-center-point-instead-of-upper-left-corner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `CSS` to perform such pulse action? If it is used you can have

`transform-box: fill-box` and `transform-align:center` for the svg.

```
path{
  transform-box:fill-box;
  transform-origin:center;
}
```

and it works.

```css
path{
  transform-box:fill-box;
  transform-origin:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="223px" height="217px" viewBox="0 0 223 217" enable-background="new 0 0 223 217" xml:space="preserve">
<!-- Start Center Click -->
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="91.5" y1="104.1582" x2="129.623" y2="104.1582">
            <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#F99F1C" />
            <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#EB6524" />
        </linearGradient>
  
        <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" d="M115.125,95.979c0,1.116-0.904,2.021-2.021,2.021l0,0c-1.116,0-2.021-0.905-2.021-2.021v-8.834
 c0-1.116,0.905-2.021,2.021-2.021l0,0c1.116,0,2.021,0.905,2.021,2.021V95.979z M106.906,116.353c0.789-0.789,0.789-2.068,0-2.857
 l0,0c-0.789-0.789-2.068-0.79-2.857,0l-6.247,6.246c-0.79,0.789-0.789,2.068,0,2.857l0,0c0.79,0.79,2.068,0.79,2.857,0
 L106.906,116.353z M93.521,105.337c-1.115,0-2.021,0.904-2.021,2.021l0,0c0,1.116,0.905,2.021,2.021,2.021h8.834
 c1.116,0,2.021-0.905,2.021-2.021l0,0c0-1.116-0.904-2.021-2.021-2.021H93.521z M100.66,91.51c-0.789-0.789-2.068-0.789-2.857,0l0,0
 c-0.789,0.79-0.789,2.069,0,2.858l6.247,6.247c0.789,0.789,2.068,0.789,2.857,0l0,0c0.79-0.789,0.789-2.068,0-2.857L100.66,91.51z
  M129.031,94.368c0.789-0.789,0.789-2.068,0-2.857l0,0c-0.789-0.79-2.068-0.789-2.857,0l-6.246,6.246
 c-0.789,0.789-0.789,2.068,0,2.857l0,0c0.789,0.79,2.068,0.789,2.857,0L129.031,94.368z" >
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" id="click1"
   type="scale"
   additive="sum" 
   from="1 1"
   to="0 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="0"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
  />
 </path>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: [svg rotate-animation (transform-origin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721937/svg-rotate-animation-transform-origin/52723036#52723036)

Answer (score 0):

SVGs scale from the origin (0,0) but there a few things you could do.

(1) You could reposition your PATH to be centered on the origin - which would involve changing all your PATH coordinates.

(2) If you're not averse to using an additional Javascript library, you could use GSAP (aka. TweenMax) which is very good at animating SVGs: https://greensock.com/svg-tips

CodePen of the solution: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/qJryda

New JS code which replaces your SMIL:

```
var shape = document.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];
TweenMax.to(shape, 2, {scale: 0, transformOrigin:"50% 50%", yoyo: true, repeat: -1});
```

(3) There are also other SMIL-based solutions you will find on StackOverflow, eg. [SVG Scale Animation from Center Point instead of Upper-Left Corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260184/svg-scale-animation-from-center-point-instead-of-upper-left-corner). I am less familiar with these as I've avoided SMIL so far, but it may suit your current needs.

Comment: you mean it's not possible without javascript?

Comment: No that's not correct. I proposed three different answers (which I have now numbered). Only the second answer requires JS.